# Round numbers in excel to 4 digits

Tags: excel, excel-formula, rounding

I need the numbers to be rounded off to 4 digits. Examples are as below:

452.658 = 452.7

45.268 = 45.27

4.2568 = 4.257

0.42586 = 0.426

The final rounded values on the right contain only 4 digits.

What formula could be used?

Answer (score 3):

Please try:

```
=ROUND(A1,5-FIND(".",A1))
```

Comment: It seems yours is the only solution that reproduces the desired results.  The others interpreted the question to mean four **significant** digits, whereas yours correctly converted `0.42586` to `0.426`  (vs `0.4259`)

Comment: To account for whole numbers try `=ROUND(A9,IFERROR(5-FIND(".",A9),4-LEN(A9)))` eg `123456` --> `123500`

Answer (score 0):

Change the digits value to the number of digits you want and you use the following formula, then you will get the result as you showed in your question:

```
=ROUND(A1,digits-(1+INT(LOG10(ABS(A1)))))
=ROUND(A1,4-(1+INT(LOG10(ABS(A1)))))
```

Source: https://exceljet.net/formula/round-a-number-to-n-significant-digits

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=ROUND(A1,4-(LEN(INT(A1)))+(A1<1))
```